# Paytm php sdk integration PaymentDetailBuilder Class not found

Tags: php, server, sdk, integration, paytm

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PaymentDetailBuilder' not found

initial code is like this:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use paytmpg\merchant\models\PaymentDetail\PaymentDetailBuilder;
use paytmpg\merchant\models\PaymentStatusDetail\PaymentStatusDetailBuilder;
use paytmpg\merchant\models\RefundDetail\RefundDetailBuilder;
use paytmpg\merchant\models\RefundStatusDetail\RefundStatusDetailBuilder;
// For Staging 
$environment = LibraryConstants::STAGING_ENVIRONMENT;

// For Production 
// $environment = LibraryConstants::PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT;

// Find your mid, key, website in your Paytm Dashboard at https://dashboard.paytm.com/next/apikeys 
$mid = MERCHANT_MID;
$key = MERCHANT_KEY;
$website = MERCHANT_WEBSITE;
$client_id = MERCHANT_CLIENT_ID;

  $callbackUrl = MERCHANT_CALLBACK_URL;
  MerchantProperties::setCallbackUrl($callbackUrl);

  MerchantProperties::initialize($environment, $mid, $key, $client_id, $website);
  // If you want to add log file to your project, use below code
  // Config::$monologName = '[PAYTM]';
  // Config::$monologLevel = MonologLogger::INFO;
  // Config::$monologLogfile = 'file.log';


    $channelId = EChannelId::WEB;
    $orderId = "ORDER_ID".rand(0,99); // post order id 
    $txnAmount = Money::constructWithCurrencyAndValue(EnumCurrency::INR, "11.00"); // post amount to be paid
    $userInfo = new UserInfo("CUSTID_002"); 
    $userInfo->setAddress("CUSTOMER_ADDRESS");
    $userInfo->setEmail("CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ID");
    $userInfo->setFirstName("CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME");
    $userInfo->setLastName("CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME");
    $userInfo->setMobile("CUSTOMER_MOBILE_NO");
    $userInfo->setPincode("CUSTOMER_PINCODE");
    $paymentDetailBuilder = new PaymentDetailBuilder($channelId, $orderId, $txnAmount, $userInfo);
    $paymentDetail = $paymentDetailBuilder->build();
    $response = Payment::createTxnToken($paymentDetail);

    print_r($response);
```

I have copied from => https://developer.paytm.com/docs/server-sdk/php/?ref=serverSdk#SDKCode;

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Please run **composer update paytm/paytm-pg** it will work.